# jQuery: nextEl = someEl.next(function() {... return true/false; })?

Tags: jquery, dom, traversal

How can I get the nearest next element that sattisfies some condition/function? Like:

`nextEl = someEl.next(function() {... return true to return this from next() });`

I'm not aware that the .next() method in jQuery API supports a function as an argument. Is there some trick to write it like this without doing a while loop?

Also I don't want to select all elements first and then use filter() -- this suboptimal from performance point of view.

Comment: Are you completely certain that it's a condition that could not be met by another selector?

Comment: Yes. Also I don't want to select all elements first and then use filter() -- this suboptimal from performance point of view.

Comment: I updated my answer to turn the native code version into a plugin called `nextMatch()`, so the condition doesn't run more times than it has to, and you don't fetch all the next siblings with `nextAll()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get all the next elements [using `.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/), then [use `.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and return the result of the condition. When the condition returns `true`, the element is kept.

Then narrow it down to [the `.first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) match.

```
nextEl = someEl.nextAll().filter(function() {
    return ( someCondition );
}).first();
```

Or if there will be many elements tested, and you don't want to run the condition all those extra times, use `.each()`, then `return false;` when the condition is met. This halts the loop.

```
var nextEl;

someEl.nextAll().each(function() {
    if( someCondition ) {
        nextEl = this;  // reference the matched element
        return false;   // break the loop
    }
});
```

---

**EDIT:** If you don't want to select *all* the next elements, I'd go native, and use a `while` loop, something like this:

```
var nextEl = someEl[0];

while( nextEl = nextEl.nextSibling ) {
    if( someCondition ) {
        break;
    }
}
```

The loop will break as soon as the condition is met, and the most recent assignment to `nextEl` will be your element.

If the condition is never met, the loop will end when it runs out of elements, and `nextEl` will be `null` or `undefined` ( I don't remember which ).

This should be a very quick way to do it.

---

**EDIT:**

Here's a function version of it. It accepts the starting element and a function that runs the test. Then it returns the match found, or `undefined`.

```
function nextMatch( el, func ) {
    while( el = el.nextSibling ) {
        if( func() ) {
            return el;
        }
    }
}

  // nextEl will contain the match, or "undefined"
var nextEl = nextMatch( someEl, function() {
    return (someTest);
});

var someOtherEl = nextMatch( someEl, function() {
    return (someOtherTest);
});
```

---

**LAST EDIT:**

I guess I might as well make it into a plugin:

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.nextMatch = function( func ) {
        return this.map(function() {
            var el = this;
            while( el = el.nextSibling ) {
                if( el.nodeType === 1 && func.call( el ) ) {
                    return el;
                }
            }
        });
    }
})( jQuery );

var nextEl = someEl.nextMatch( function() {
    return (someTest);
});
```

So now it's more of a jQuery type solution. You still should have better performance since it doesn't fetch all the next siblings, and the `while` loop still breaks once a match is found.

Comment: This works, but  there is some performace penalty for selecting all the elements So I wanted to not use that.

Comment: @tillda - Is the penalty in the condition test, or just in selecting the elements. I added an answer that halts the conditions after the first time it is satisfied. If you didn't want the `.nextAll()`, you could use a `while` loop. I'll give an update.

Comment: Actually the `return false;` inside the `filter` doesn't break the loop. It just discards that element from the results of `filter`. So, in fact, this selects the last matching sibling (look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cambraca/vQPC4/1/))

Comment: @cambraca - That was a `copy/paste` error. In the description you'll see I should have `.each()` there instead. I also missed the closing `}` for the `if()`. Thanks for the heads up. Fixed. :o)

Comment: But if performance is really a concern, I like your native js idea.

Comment: @cambraca - Agreed. Native should always be quicker. [Here's your test](http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/vQPC4/4/) using the `while` loop.

Comment: I have about 20-30 of these similar but different loops in my application, so that's why I'm asking if there is some simple API way. Thanks for answering anyway!

Comment: @tillda - Do you mean that they are essentially the same except for the condition test? If so, you could just make a function out of it that receives the test as a function parameter that is called.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
nextEl = someEl.nextAll('.a').first().css('color', 'red');
```

The condition is in this case that it has the class `a`, and it turns the color red (merely as an indicator).

Look at it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cambraca/vQPC4/).

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I want. I want to specify if by a **function**. Also I don't want to match all elements first because of performance.

Comment: you can use `next()` to do that: `nextEl = someEl.next('.a');`

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: actually, you cannot. If the next element doesn't match, it doesn't look further, it just returns nothing.

Comment: you're right, I misunderstood `it is excluded` in the docs. Thanks :)

Comment: To specify a function, use patrick's first answer (with `filter`)